# Why is gravitational potential energy $= mgh$? And how is it useful to us?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

- Who introduced the concept of gravitational potential energy?
- Why do we need it to describe the physical world and how is it useful to us?
- And from where does the formula $ U = mgh$ come from?

Comment: Are you "comfortable" with the definition of work as W=Fd?

Comment: Yes I am @David White

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there doesn't appear to have been any research. This link has information which will basically answer the questions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy

Comment: Bill, i researched but what's written on Wikipedia doesn't convince me on how was the formula derived

Comment: @TheSalameless Why aren't you convinced by the wikipedia article? What is your difficulty?

Comment: @BillN and co. why off topic? The questions are reasonable and none of the answers here  or the mentioned Wikipedia article actually give the correct answer at least for point 3. Which consists of 1) the gravitational two body problem for a planet and a stone is approximated in an obvious way, and 2) $V(r0+h) = V(r0)+mgh +O(h^2)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The physics definition of work is $W=Fd$, where $W$ is work, $F$ is force, and $d$ is displacement.  Only the component of force that acts in the direction of the displacement adds to work.

With this definition in mind, note that the gravitational force on an object at the surface of the earth is $mg$.  For "small" vertical displacements (e.g., a few hundred meters or less), it is safe to assume that the value of $g$ remains constant, so the gravitational force on the object in question remains constant.  Given that fact, the work done to elevate an object from position $y_0$ to position $y_f$ is $mg(y_f - y_0)$.  This equation is usually expressed as $W=mgh$, where $h=(y_f-y_0)$.

Regarding the nomenclature of $U=mgh$, note that work is equivalent to energy, so work done to elevate an object changes the object's gravitational potential energy by an equivalent amount, which leads to the equivalent equation $U=mgh$.  However, note that this is the change in gravitational potential energy, so a term of $\Delta U$ would probably be more appropriate on the left hand side of this equation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer helped me immediately understand the concept

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we need it to describe the physical world and how is it useful
>   to us?

@David White has answered the first and third bulleted questions. This pertains to the second.

How useful is it? Consider that in 2015 (according to Wikipedia) 16.6% of the world's total electricity and 70% of all renewable electricity was produced from hydropower.

Hydropower, or hydroelectricity, is ultimately produced by converting gravitational potential energy of water at an elevation to kinetic energy. The most common hydroelectric power plants uses a dam on a river that stores water in a reservoir. Water released from the reservoir flows through a turbine, spinning it, which in turn operates a generator to produce electricity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it does help, thanks

Comment: I appreciate your acceptance of my answer. But it was really intended to complement David White's answer, not replace it. His was the most comprehensive and should remain the accepted answer. A simple up vote of mine would be sufficient.